# MySQL cross reference table join

Tags: mysql, search, join

I am pretty new to sql and searching the forum did not give me the right answer, so I place a new one. I have three tables:

Products

- product_id
- product_description

Keywords

- keyword_id
- Keyword_description

And a reference table keywords_to_products:

- reference_id
- keyword_id-> relates to keywords table
- product_id -> relates to products table

I am looking for two queries :

- One that gives all products matching one OR more specific keywords (I think I already have this) 
  ie: all products having the keywords 'bolt' OR 'screw'
- One that gives all products matching multiple keywords (AND) this is the one I don't get...
  ie: all products having the keywords 'bolt' AND 'nut'

Although I think it is not the most exciting thing to do, I just cannot figure it out.

Besides, I am wondering if I do the right thing anyway.

I am writing an application having appr. 1.000.000 different products in it with an article number and a description. I add important words from the description to the keyword database and also add additional keywords like EAN number or equivalent productnumber which are not in the product table.
These are all connected through the keyword-to-product table.

Every keyword, even EAN numbers for example, can refer to multiple products.

The idea is searching through the keyword_to_product_table only instead of searching through multiple fields in the products table. Good idea ??

Thanks in advance for your replies..

Regards, Arno Verkley

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select distinct p.Id, p.Description
from Product p 
join ProductKeyword pk
  on p.id = pk.ProductId
join Keyword k
  on k.id = pk.KeyWordId
  and k.description in ("Red", "Yellow")
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6053/3

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. This works for the first 'or' option, but not in the 'and' option. In that case the result should only contain foo which has both 'red' and 'yellow' as keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Searching directly in your main table, say in the description column, you would have a where looking like this

```
WHERE 
  description like "%bolt%"
and description like "%nut%"
```

Now using a keyword table (product_id, keyword), I can suggest

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(p.*)
FROM Product p
JOIN ProductKeyword pk1
ON p.id = pk1.productId
JOIN ProductKeyword pk2
ON p.id = pk2.productId
WHERE
  pk1.keyword = "bolt"
AND
  pk2.keyword = "nut"
```

And yes, a keyword_to_product table sounds a good idea. You can use an index on keyword, that will keep your queries fast (when the 'like' operator will slow down a lot queries on a big table).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks a lot for the answers !

A little bit of both answers seem to do the trick (on the fiddle; by the way thanks for this very usefull trial and error tool, although it is not very fast ;o(  )

```
SELECT distinct p.id, p.descriptionFROM Product p

JOIN ProductKeyword pk1
  ON p.id = pk1.ProductId

join Keyword k1
  on k1.id = pk1.KeyWordId

JOIN ProductKeyword pk2
  ON p.id = pk2.ProductId

join Keyword k2
  on k2.id = pk2.KeyWordId

WHERE
 k1.description = "Yellow"
AND
 k2.description = "Red"
```

With indexes on the id's and keyword.description will this be the fastest method ?? And what if I will be using more then two keywords ?? just add more joins and where's ??

Regards, Arno

Comment: yes, more joins and where is the way to do it. Again, with the right indexes, it's fast.